# IN inside a case statement of WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to add IN inside a case statement of WHERE clause as below:

```
WHERE

CASE WHEN @id IN(1,2) THEN ...
CASE WHEN @id IN(3,4) THEN...
```

I got syntax error...I then tried by removing IN adding OR as below:

```
CASE WHEN @id = 1 OR @id = 2 THEN ...
CASE WHEN @id = 3 OR @id = 4 THEN ...
```

It worked....but just for curiosity I want to know whether somehow we can use IN...
please help

Comment: AFAIK this should be valid...what else was in the clause?

Comment: What comes after `THEN..`? Usually case statements go within your select statement, and to use `IN` here you would normally say `WHERE @id IN(1,2)..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explain further.  This is definitely valid syntax:

```
DECLARE @id int = 1

SELECT 'Foo'
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @id IN (1,3) THEN 1
          ELSE 0 
          END
```

What is in your `THEN` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to put the condition in parenthesis, like:

```
( @id IN(1,2) )
```